# Sphinx: Avoid new paragraph in multilinestruct-type parameter description

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to document my function in Sphinx that takes a dictionary as a parameter and I'd like to describe its keys. This is an example of how I'm writing docstrings (Numpy-Style):

```
def demoFunction(settings):
    """Some description

    Parameters
    ----------
    settings : `dict`
        Settings dictionary with keys:

        ``"color"``
            Hex colour code (`str`).
        ``"size"``
            Point area in pixels (`float`).
        ``"complicatedKey"``
            A key with a complicated description. Like any definition list item,
            the content can be wrapped. You can include lists inside the item as well:

            - The first item of the list. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
            adipiscing elit.

            Proin nulla magna, egestas quis nisi id, dictum mollis diam. Duis lorem
            eros, tempor egestas ligula eget, dapibus posuere justo.

            - The second item of the list.

            You can also include multiple paragraphs in a key's description. Ensure that
            all content is aligned with the opening content line.
    """
    return False
```

And this is the output I get:

[image]

How can I prevent the description ("Settings dictionary with keys:") from going into a new paragraph? I want it in the same paragraph with **settings** (*dict*) –

In the `conf.py` I used these extensions to render the Numpy-Style Docstrings:

```
extensions = [
    'myst_parser',
    'sphinx.ext.duration',
    'sphinx.ext.doctest',
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'sphinx.ext.autosummary',
    'sphinx.ext.intersphinx',
    'nbsphinx',
    'sphinx.ext.napoleon'
]

# Napoleon settings
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try putting all this on one line? `settings : dict Settings dictionary with keys:`

Comment: I finally found the solution by simply setting `napoleon_use_param = False` in the `conf.py`